# attempting to loop through an array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to go through an array called a and filter the ones that are in array b, for some reason it gives me this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'int[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
     public static int[] ArrayDiff(int[] a, int[] b)
     {
        return a.ToList().Where(num => (b.ToList().Contains(num)));
     }
```

Comment: `return a.Where(num => (b.Contains(num)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 3):

`.Where()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, but your method returns an `int[]`.  You can convert the results to an array to return them:

```
return a.ToList().Where(num => (b.ToList().Contains(num))).ToArray();
```

**Or** you can change your method signature to return `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ArrayDiff(int[] a, int[] b)
```

Comment: Oh, so what I wrote is fine but the return value is the error? Thanks!

Comment: @fdsfds: As an academic exercise, definitely take a look at things like `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>`, etc. instead of using arrays.  You may find them a bit more robust to work with.  It's still important to understand plain arrays, of course.  But there are additional tools available to you.

Comment: Once you go `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` you never go back!

Comment: Ha-ha, answer has rating `4`, OP's question has rating `-1`. That's funny.

Comment: @JohnyL: In extreme cases there's even a much-coveted badge for it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal

Comment: You can also remove the redundant `ToList()` for `a` and `b` since arrays also implements `IEnumerable` and therefor you can use the `Where` extension method directly on them.

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query returns result of type `IEnumerable<T>`. And you must explicitly convert it to `int[]`.

Change:

```
a.ToList().Where(num => (b.ToList().Contains(num)));
```

to:

```
a.Where(num => (b.Contains(num))).ToArray();
```